# Why was it closed?

Tags: discussion, close-reasons, deleted-questions

I ***had*** a question asking about assessing default `__init__` of python code objects, no one answered it I was some-what heavily down-voted (did get a single up-vote), and was put-off topic and deleted. I think the main reason was actually because of people not being familiar with python code objects and the `compile` function, so I am firmly aware that it may be impossible to bring it back I don't think questions should be closed and deleted for a lack of people knowing anything about the topic.
[default __init__ for code objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25084043/default-init-for-code-objects)

Comment: No, questions don't get closed by people having no idea about. Normally it is because the question itself is a problem. Which question is it you refer to? You want to know the reason for closure, right? 10k+ users still can see the question if you provide a link

Comment: Please provide a link to the question in question, if you want our help in explaining why it was closed/deleted.  Of course, you can start out with the close reason; that should be a pretty big hint as to what is wrong with the question.

Comment: questions get closed by close votes, and you can't close "because you don't understand" there was something in the question itself for sure.  either unclear, too broad, asking about opinion, or simply a lack of clarity/research.

Comment: It was deleted and I can't find any sort of link to it at all.

Comment: Look in your browser history. Otherwise this is just a rant

Comment: @juergend not to defend or anything, but.... isn't there a way for certain high reps users/moderators to see deleted questions?

Comment: Found it:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25084043/default-init-for-code-objects

Comment: @Julldar 10k users can see the question when given a link to it, but they cannot find the question if they don't already have the link.

Comment: @Julldar any user having [10K reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/moderator-tools) can see deleted questions

Comment: That question was deleted by the automatic site cleanup process for older unanswered closed questions. It wasn't deleted by any users. I've undeleted it to allow for further discussion.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your question was closed because it was unclear for several readers, and several suggestions were given as to what information you may want to include to help make your question clearer.

Because the question had a negative score and was closed, it was deleted automatically by a cleanup script 10 days after being posted given that you failed to improve the question sufficiently in response to the problems described.

No user/person explicitly deleted the question.

The question was not closed because people didn't know how to solve the problem, it was closed (enabling possible deletion) because they didn't understand what it is you were asking in the first place.  That is a key distinction.

Comment: The downvoting/closing of questions by people who just don't get it seems to be a widespread problem as Stack Overflow covers a huge field of different technologies. Should we consider technical or some other means to stop people from reacting negatively if the area of the question is just not familiar enough to understand the question?

Comment: @jkj I don't see it as a widespread problem at all.  It certainly wasn't a problem here.  Deep technically knowledge is mostly just important when it comes to duplicates, and in that situation users with a deeper technical knowledge *are* given greater tools to interact with such questions.